# Rails 4 file upload with Dropzone.js using Paperclip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, paperclip, dropzone.js

I have a model object that can have one image. When I create new objects I would like to be able to drag and drop new images, using [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com). The model object have other attributes as well, like name, etc. So the form have multiple fields. I want something that looks something like this:

```
 Name *:
 ------------------------ 
 I                       I
 ------------------------

Image:

---------------------------------
I                               I
I          Dropzone             I
I                               I
---------------------------------

                           Submit
```

I present the form using a `Boostrap JS` [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). I'm struggling to get the drop zone presented as I want (or at all). My form currently looks like this (I use `HAML`):

```
= form_for @idea, remote: remote, html: {role: :form, "data-model" => 'idea', multipart: true}  do |f|

.form-group
  = f.label :name, "Title", :class => "required"
  = f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control"

# I have tried to create a form within the form (in some different ways), but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach...

%form{class: "dropzone"}
  .fallback
    = f.file_field :image
```

Now the drop zone isn't displayed at all. I have verified that the files are properly installed. If I add `class: "dropzone"` to my `form_for` line, then the drop zone displays, but covers the whole form (including the other fields).

I used `'dropzonejs-rails'` to install `Dropzone`.

Any ideas on what I can do to achieve the effect I want?

**Update**

The relevant part of the generated form looks like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/ideas" class="new_idea" data-model="idea" data-remote="true" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_idea" method="post" role="form">

    <form class='dropzone'></form>
      <div class='fallback'>
        <input id="idea_image" name="idea[image]" type="file" />
      </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
      <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Idea" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are there any errors reported in the browser console? Also, can you post the HTML form code that's generated?

Comment: @EgeErsoz I have updated my question with the relevant parts of the generated form. Found `<form class='dropzone'></form>`, looks wrong.  I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it however.

Comment: That looks about right. Dropzone.js looks for form elements with class `dropzone` and attaches itself to them. Are there any errors in the browser console? Can you reproduce it in jsfiddle if you copy the HTML there and include the required javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a different container than the form with the `previewsContainer` option to Dropzone. For example, you might just use a div and add the `dropzone-previews` class as follows:

```
= form_for @idea, remote: remote, html: {role: :form, "data-model" => 'idea', multipart: true}  do |f|

  .form-group
    = f.label :name, "Title", :class => "required"
    = f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control"

  .dropzone-previews
    %p.dz-message You can drop an image here or click to upload.

    .fallback
      = f.file_field :image

:javascript
  Dropzone.options.#{@ideas} = {
    previewsContainer: '.dropzone-previews',
    ...
  }
```

As documented on the [Dropzone.js page](http://www.dropzonejs.com/):

> previewsContainer defines where to display the file previews – if null the Dropzone element is used. Can be a plain HTMLElement or a CSS selector. The element should have the dropzone-previews class so the previews are displayed properly.